# Variadic template for both typenames and scalar constants

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm trying to implement a generic class template which forwards it's template arguments to another class, like this:

```
template <typename... Args>
class A : public B<Args...>
{
    ...
```

The problem is what B can have scalar constant template like this:

```
template <size_t N>
class B
{
    ...
```

or even like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class B
{
    ...
```

So, is there any way to accept mixed up typenames and scalar constants as a variadic template parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed values into types. This is a technique long used by boost if I recalled correctly, and was added to the standard library in C++11 as `std::integral_constant` (indicative of its usefulness).

With C++17, things got even simpler.

```
template<auto val>
struct constant : std::integral_constant<decltype(val), val> {};
```

In conjunction with an alias `B2` for `B`, you use it as

```
template<typename T, typename N>
struct B2 { using type = B<T, N::value>; };

template<typename... Args>
struct A : public B2<Args...>::type {};

A<int, constant<42>> a;
```

Comment: It seems it's the best possible solution for the current standart, thank you.